# System Files iMovie 10 & 8.0.6 Garage Band 10 & 5.1

Tags: imovie, plist, garageband

I am trying to remove some clutter from my HardDrive.

I notice that I have both iMovie 10 and iMover ver8.0.6 installed.
Similarly I have Garageband 10 and Garageband 5.1 installed.

I would like to remove the plists, folders and anything that is specific to the old versions without deleting something that is also used by the newer versions.

Can anyone list for me all the files and folders that are necessary to run
just iMovie 10?

and a list of the system files and folders necessary for just Garageband 10?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I did the test with iMovie 10

It shows following files associated with it:

[image: movie 10]

Since Apple changed iMovie & Garageband significantly, it does not automatically uninstall the older version because there are still some people who want to stick with the older one. If you tried and liked the new one, you can simply put the older version in trash.

Comment: What app did you use to list all these files & folders?

Comment: @IconDaemon AppCleaner.app :)